# Free open maps for embedding on an application

Tags: javascript, dictionary, gis

Apart from Googlemaps and OpenStreetMaps, which other maps can I freely embed on my website at that are interactive (i.e. not static)?

Any relevant URL for sites that can assist me in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There have been extensive discussions on this topic over at gis.stackexchange, e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8032/comparison-of-javascript-mapping-libraries

Comment: Thanks. I like this discussion. It has really opened up my mapping knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bing map

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877180.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692181.aspx

Comment: Thanks i'll explore the bing maps. Are bing maps free?

Comment: yes, last year i use it. yandex already provides a api but it doesn't have documentation in english. http://api.yandex.ru/maps/